# Как установить Symfony на windows 7?

Tags: php, symfony, framework

Меня мучает такой вопрос: почему при скачивании фреймворка Symfony у меня и автора курса (смотрю курс по Symfony) разный результат? Например у автора  после установки имеется папка App у меня нет. Хотя я делал все абсолютно также. Опять же, после долгих сомнений, я выслал то что у меня получилось программисту. Требования были что бы я увидел страницу приветствия Symfony. Cказал сменить версию php c моей 7.1... на 7.2.5 и дописал в .yaml файл нужные строки. Работает. Но.. Теперь хочу вместо своего Open Server использовать встроенный сервер Symfony. Иду в документацию, скачиваю... опять проблема та же. Никаких обновлений не вижу, хотя ошибок Composer не выдавал. Зашел в .yaml файл, там все вроде прописано. В чем тут может быть проблема?

Comment: Например, в том что автор курса делал уроки по одной версии symfony, а вы установили другую версию

Comment: Ну что вас конкретно интересует? То что у автора и у вас результат разный в виде чего, оформление немного отличается? Это норма, ну или же `composer.json` и чекайте версию `symfony`. Опишите проблему конкретно. Вы даже не указали, какие конкретно проблемы с запуском сервера от `symfony`.

Comment: Симфони поднимается вообще на изи + сервер одной командой доставляется и так же одной командой поднимается, а результат так же может быть разный, если автор курса скелет другой проекта поставил, но в курсе указан иной, как вариант.

Comment: Здравствуйте! Не могу чётко обосновать свою проблему пардон конечно. Наверно так и есть разный скелет) А можно сделать так, чтобы было точно как у автора? Собственно сам в песочнице нахожусь, не очень понял зачем и гитхаб?. Для обмена кодом если, то за коим? Вы пишите трудитесь, а кто-то слизывает ваш код? А в обмен не факт что будет код нормальный? И злоумышленники, которые видят код вашего проекта хоть какой? Я так понимаю что и во всех фреймворкак (или многих) есть гитхаб.... а безопасность сайтов на сим данном фреймворке?